# How do I update my encrypted phone (CyanogenMod 12)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, recovery-mode, encryption

I want to encrypt my phone(Xperia M). It has CyanogenMod 12 with cyanogenmod recovery. Wanted to know if I could update it the normal way, flashing through recovery, or some other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 04-01-2015 custom recoveries don't support decryption CM12 yet. It will give you a *wrong password* notification when trying to decrypt.

But you can put the `update.zip` in `/cache` partition. Then in the recovery, skip entering the password. And flash from `/cache` partition. 
This works because you don't need your password to access `/cache` partition.

Answer (score 0):

In upgrading to CM13, I would do wipe both caches, system and data. It is enough demanding for the system to the upgrade also without system encryption. However, I have managed to several updates in encrypted systems as Sparta describes but after many of them something often breaks and fresh installation can be necessary.